# Recommended Foursquare venue information cache age?

Tags: caching, foursquare

In order to stay within the rate limits imposed by the [Foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs), they previously recommended caching the data requested from it. However, after the recent site redesign, information on how long data should be cached is nowhere to be found. According to [archive.org's WayBack machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160506055803/https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/categories), the documentation for the [venues/categories endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/categories) previously said that the data for that endpoint should be cached for no more than a week, so I've implemented that in my app. That information is no longer on that documentation page. I'm now looking to cache the data from the [venues/ endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/details) (all the data of specific places), and likewise, no information about cache age is found, and I don't remember if there was any before. Would the 1 week previously recommended by the venues/categories endpoint be a reasonable cache lifetime for data from venues/? If not, what would be? The [API Terms of Use](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/terms-of-use/overview) say that no data can be cached more than 30 days without being updated, but that seems like a long time to keep data from a constantly-updated, crowdsourced platform. What cache age has worked well for you in the past?

Comment: Why not just use the API in real-time to keep your application fresh and save you from implementing any cache?

Comment: Ultimately, I'll probably have to do this to an extent so I can use the `isOpen` flag from the `venues/` endpoint in a specific case, but my use case involves making a `limit=50` call to `venues/search` and then doing a lookup in `venues/` for potentially every venue returned (in the worst case, which might not be too uncommon). That would burn API calls *fast*, so caching is likely fairly important for me to not hit the call limit

Comment: True. What field do you need from `venues/` that doesn't come back in `/search`?

Comment: `price` and `isOpen`. Eventually I'm going to try to figure out a strategy for caching `hours` based on the `timeZone` it gives, but that's a bit complex for my 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their [new documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/terms-of-use/overview#data-retention), as of May 15, 2018, Foursquare requires that all data must be cached for no more than 24 hours